# getting all the tiles with the maximum value in a 2d grid (a multidimensional list)

Tags: python, list, max

I have a 2d grid (multidimensional list) like maybe so: `[[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[1,1,1]]` and I want to get the positions of all elements that contain the max values, so in this case that would be: `(0,3), (1,1)`and`(1,2)`.

I now have a very clumsy way which works, like this:

```
max_val = -999999
for i in range(board.get_dim()):
    for j in range(board.get_dim()):
        if scores[i][j] > max_val:
            max_val = scores[i][j]

max_coords = []            
for i in range(board.get_dim()):
    for j in range(board.get_dim()):
        if scores[i][j] == max_val:
            max_coords.append((i,j))
```

But I was hoping if someone could point me to a more concise solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) to get the max value and then use a list comprehension with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
##find the max value on a flattened version of the list 
>>> max_val = max(chain.from_iterable(lst)) 
>>> lst = [[1,2,3], [1,3,3], [1,1,1]]
>>> [(i, j) for i, x in enumerate(lst) for j, y in enumerate(x) if y == max_val]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

NumPy makes it very easy though:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(lst)
>>> zip(*np.where(arr==arr.max()))
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: There's also [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) which returns the index right away.

Comment: @Midnighter It returns only the first index, OP wants all of them.